# Ubuntu network file-sharing

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba, file-sharing, avahi

This couldn't be simpler, but I've failed to get it working, so I hope some Samba or Avahi experts can help me here.

I have a laptop and a desktop on a home network both running Ubuntu 19.10, along with a bunch of Android devices and an occasional Windows XP or Vista machine, or Virtual Windows 7. The laptop(s) may also be on other networks which I can control.

My objective is to share a partition from the Ubuntu laptop to the desktop. Principally so I can use Darktable, Digikam and the desktop's larger screen to view and edit images. This depends on name resolution and consistent network names.

How hard can it be?

I set up Samba on both machines (samba version 2:4.10.7+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3, samba-common, samba-common-bin), and nautilus-share. After much messing around I was able to connect to shared folders both ways using smb://ip-address/ in Nautilus and smbclient in the command terminal.

However I couldn't connect from the machine names; Nautilus returned the error:

> > '**Unable to access location** Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused'

Command terminal:

```
$ smbclient -L ////JohnsMacBookPro//Pictures -U john
Unable to initialize messaging context
do_connect: Connection to JohnsMacBookPro failed (Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)
```

For some reason the laptop was using NT1 and the desktop SMB3; I couldn't get to the bottom of this. And forcing versions by setting client and server min and max to SMB3 didn't change matters.

So, following @Morbius1's suggestion in this thread [Bionic Beaver can not discover samba hosts - netbios](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384959), for simple Ubuntu networking, I:

1) Purged and reinstalled samba on both machines - samba, samba-common, samba-common-bin. I didn't edit the smb.conf.

2) Created an /etc/avahi/services/samba.service file on both machines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
   <name replace-wildcards="yes">SMB %h</name> ## Display Name
   <service>
       <type>_smb._tcp</type>
       <port>445</port>
   </service>
</service-group>
```

3) Added and enabled samba users on both machines:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a john
sudo smbpasswd -e john
```

4) Used Nautilus to shared the Pictures partition and a sambashare folder from the laptop, and a sambashare folder from the desktop.

Now I can connect using the names - although there's duplication in Nautilus' network folders list. But the partition name has a number appended, which changes. This is a problem for an application like Digikam which expects to find resources in the same place every time it runs.

After rebooting the laptop, Nautilus on the desktop, 'Other locations', 'Network' shows 7 icons (possibly a reboot would clean this up):

```
Folder icon: 'pictures on johnsmacbookpro-15.local' which links
Folder icon: 'pictures on johnsmacbookpro-9.local' which linked yesterday, not today
Network drive icon: 'SMB JohnsMacBookPro-15' clicking on which generated the matching folder and mount point
Network drive icon: 'SMB Desktop01' which links to sambashare folder and print
Network drive icon: 'DESKTOP01 (File Sharing)' which links as above
Windows Network, leading to WORKGROUP and resources JOHNSMACBOOKPRO and DESKTOP01. Clicking on DESKTOP01 leads to the shared folders. JOHNSMACBOOKPRO generates the error message '**Unable to access location** Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused' (as before from samba when accessing network resources)
Network drive icon: 'DESKTOP01 (File Sharing)' which links as above
```

The laptop's Other Locations - Networks list is simpler as whilst it shows 'SMB JohnsMacBookPro-15' it lists and links to 'DESKTOP01' and 'SMB Desktop01' without the appended numbers.

Output of testparm -s on both machines is the unaltered basic smb.conf:

```
$ testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
```

My immediate problems would be resolved if I can get a consistent name for the laptop, which I presume is from the Avahi / msdns packages?

Samba appears to have the same problems it always had. Not sure if those are soluble, might be a better solution in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this will be an iterative process.

The problem here is samba can resolve machines by name two different ways: By NetBIOS name and by its mDNS / Avahi name. Nautilus will display both by default if everyhing is working but it displays it with the same name followed by ( File Sharing ). NetBIOS is flaky so you may or may not be able to make a connection. Avahi is fairly consistent and is built into 19.10.

Here's the first thing I would do on both machine:

[1] Make sure you have the /etc/avahi/services/samba.service file on both machines.

[2] Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf on both machines and right under the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line add this one:

```
multicast dns register = no
```

[3] Save smb.conf and restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Your Linux machines will always appear as **SMB hostname** directly under "Other Locations" and not under "Windows Network". This is the Avahi way. There won't be any duplicates of the Avhai way since you've disabled it in smb.conf.

They may also show up under "Windows Network" but without the SMB prefix. This is the NetBIOS way. There is a way to disable this as well but then you mess with discovery from Windows machines.